# Post Request not Calle

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I'm learning node.js and I've hit a wall. My post request is not getting triggered.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
```

Setting up server

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
  console.log('request was made: ' + req.url);
  if (req.url === '/home' || req.url === '/'){
    fs.readFile("./index.html",null,function(error,data){
      if (error) throw error;
      res.write(data);
  res.end();
});
  } else {
      console.log("404");
  }
})
```

The post-request that refuse to work

```
app.post('/test', function(req,res){
  console.log("post req came thru");
})
```

Listening...

```
server.listen(8080)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CRUD App</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<form action="/test" method="POST" >
  <input type="text" name="test"></input>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the Express `app` as a parameter to the `http.createServer` function otherwise it won't be handling any of your requests. Either that, or use the actual `app.listen` method:

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```